# foreach con php y poo

Tags: php

estoy aprendiendo PHP con POO y quería imprimir un array con foreach con un objeto y me funciono:

```
class padre
{

    function __construct()
    {
        $nombres = ["Perengano", "sutano", "chilindrina"];
        foreach ($nombres as $name) {
            echo "$name <br>";
        }
    }
}
$a = new padre;
```

---

Pero ahora quiero hacerlo llamando el array desde un atributo pero no me sale o no se si se pueda hacer de la manera que yo busco.

Espero su ayuda y si se puede, algún consejo para poder mejorar mi aprendizaje en PHP, saludos  y gracias de antemano =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de este modo, declaras la estructura de la clase, pero en lugar de usar un método `__construct` que busca darle valores a una clase por defecto puedes usar un método nombrado; es decir una función así mismo para usar un `foreach` es ideal mejor declarar un `array` asociativo es decir de **clave-valor**

Al final al crear la instancia de la clase al objeto llamado $a podemos en la última línea darle un echo a dicho objeto accediendo al método imprimir que me devolverá los resultados de dicho `array`

Mira el ejemplo

```
class Datos
{
    protected $nombres;

    function imprimir()
    {
        $this->nombres = array("valor1" => "Perengano","valor2" => "sutano","valor3" => "chilindrina");
        foreach ($this->nombres as $key => $value)
        {
            echo $value.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
} 

$a = new Datos;
echo $a->imprimir();
```

Los detalle de key y value son para:

1. `$key` me devuelve por ejemplo `$valor1`, `$valor2` y `$valor3`
2. `$value` me devuelve los valores asociados a las claves del punto uno
3. Por otro lado los nombres de las clases deben iniciar con mayúscula y tener referencia al contenido de dicha clase
4. Por otro lado siempre debes indicar el alcance de una una propiedad, dentro de los cuales tienes `public`, `private` y `protected`; lo ideal es que no sean `public` para que no sean modificables fuera de la propia clase que los declaró

Ahora si quieres usar el constructor para inicializar una propiedad al momento de crear la clase quedaría de este modo y sigue siendo funcional

```
class Datos
{
    protected $nombres;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->nombres = array("valor1" => "Perengano","valor2" => "sutano","valor3" => "chilindrina");
    }

    function imprimir()
    {
        foreach ($this->nombres as $key => $value)
        {
            echo $value.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
} 

$a = new Datos();
echo $a->imprimir();
```